# Rotating a bmp and displaying it right-side-up

Tags: android, imageview, bmp, autorotate

I have an app that snaps a picture and displays the picture on an Imageview.  The problem is, I can only snap a pic in landscape mode in order for the bmp to be displayed right side up - Is there a way I can rotate it to right side up if the pic is taken in portrait mode/

Thanks!

Here is the code I use to place the image in the img view -

```
  private void processCameraImage(Intent intent) {
    setContentView(R.layout.detectlayout);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.detect_face)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    cameraBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

    imageView.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
```

There is a detect faces button that will detect if there are faces present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would rotate a bmp:

```
   private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
   {
      //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
       Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
       //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
       Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
       //move rotation point to center of image
       g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width/2,(float)b.Height / 2);
       //rotate
       g.RotateTransform(angle);
       //move image back
       g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width/2,-(float)b.Height / 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used onActivityResult() in my activity.  The intent returned was for picking an image of the type image/*.  Works well for me!

```
Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
                String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
                Cursor cur = managedQuery(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
                int orientation = -1;
                if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
                }  
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(orientation);
```